# Check for existence of specific child element in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT I am generating a table that contains a row for each `ejerlejlighed`-tag in XML (see below).

Path: forandringer->ejerlejligheder->ejerlejlighed

Each `ejerlejlighed`-tag contains a range of information that should be presented as columns, where one tag is optional: `anvendelse`.

The question:

My client has asked that a column for the `anvendelse`-tag is only shown if at least one of the `ejerlejlighed`-tags contain this information.

Path forandringer->ejerlejligheder->ejerlejlighed->anvendelse

```
    <forandringer>
    <aendrings>
        <changesOrder>1</changesOrder>
        <sagsoperationKode>EOPEF</sagsoperationKode>
        <sagsoperationBetegnelse>Oprettelse af ejerlejlighedsfællesskab</sagsoperationBetegnelse>
        <hovedejendomBFEnr>3330122</hovedejendomBFEnr>
        <hovedejendomType>SFE</hovedejendomType>
    </aendrings>
    <aendrings>
        <changesOrder>2</changesOrder>
        <sagsoperationKode>ENOPAH</sagsoperationKode>
        <sagsoperationBetegnelse>Anden hjemmel*</sagsoperationBetegnelse>
        <hovedejendomBFEnr>3330122</hovedejendomBFEnr>
        <hovedejendomType>SFE</hovedejendomType>
        <aktuelBFEnr>100229741</aktuelBFEnr>
        <aktuelEJLnr>1</aktuelEJLnr>
        <kommentar>§18</kommentar>
    </aendrings>
    <ejerlejligheder>
        <mainPropertyBFENumber>3330122</mainPropertyBFENumber>
        <ejerlejlighed>
            <BFENumber>100229741</BFENumber>
            <ejerlejlighedNr>1</ejerlejlighedNr>
            <adresse>Ukendt adresse</adresse>
            <areal>100</areal>
            <fordelingstal>25/100</fordelingstal>
        </ejerlejlighed>
        <ejerlejlighed>
            <BFENumber>100229742</BFENumber>
            <ejerlejlighedNr>2</ejerlejlighedNr>
            <adresse>Ukendt adresse</adresse>
            <anvendelse>Erhverv</anvendelse>
            <areal>200</areal>
            <fordelingstal>25/100</fordelingstal>
        </ejerlejlighed>
        <ejerlejlighed>
            <BFENumber>100229743</BFENumber>
            <ejerlejlighedNr>3</ejerlejlighedNr>
            <adresse>Ukendt adresse</adresse>
            <areal>200</areal>
            <fordelingstal>25/100</fordelingstal>
        </ejerlejlighed>
        <ejerlejlighed>
            <BFENumber>100229744</BFENumber>
            <ejerlejlighedNr>4</ejerlejlighedNr>
            <adresse>Ukendt adresse</adresse>
            <areal>200</areal>
            <fordelingstal>25/100</fordelingstal>
        </ejerlejlighed>
    </ejerlejligheder>
</forandringer>
```

To support this i have created a template that is called as below. However i don't know how to make the select statement for param `show-anvendelse` true or false based on whether an `anvendelse`-tag exists.

```
<xsl:call-template name="ejerlejlighed-table-only">
     <xsl:with-param name="lejligheder" select="current-group()"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="show-anvendelse" select="false()"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k As what i needed was the "variable for the select-attribute, i thought this was exactly that. I read through the linked post and can see that i did not achieve this quite as planned, thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of your question is not clear. There is nothing in your description that would indicate a need for grouping and/or for calling a named template.

If you are creating a row for each `ejerlejlighed`, and you want to create a specific column only when at least one `ejerlejlighed` has an `anvendelse` child, then obviously you want to make this test **once** for all the rows, and use the result in each row - here is a simplified example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/forandringer">
    <xsl:variable name="anvendelse" select="ejerlejligheder/ejerlejlighed/anvendelse" />
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="ejerlejligheder/ejerlejlighed">
            <row>
                <!-- mandatory columns -->
                <xsl:if test="$anvendelse">
                    <optional-column>
                        <!-- some value -->
                    </optional-column>
                </xsl:if>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! That would definitely have worked. 

In this case, the template that i call, is a shared template that i am obligated to use.

Comment: Well, you do not tell us why you are so obligated, and even more crucially, from what context you are calling it. So all I can tell you at this point is that the answer you have accepted is probably not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try `exists(xpath)` function:

```xslt
<xsl:call-template name="ejerlejlighed-table-only">
     <xsl:with-param name="lejligheder" select="current-group()"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="show-anvendelse" select="exists(anvendelse)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like i am able to just use "anvendelse". (I couldnt make your suggestion work).

I think i need some kind of path added to it, but i am unsure how it should look when there are several ejerlejlighed-tags to iterate through.

Comment: Show me how you call this template.

Comment: This will check if `anvendelse` exists anywhere in the document: `<xsl:if test="//anvendelse">[you code goes here]</xsl:if>`

Comment: I dont know why this did not work, but it seems like it does not evaluate to true or false.. Doing a count and comparison with greater than as suggested by bolk, worked!

Comment: @DanielKappers FYI, the [exists()](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-exists) function definitely evaluates to `true` or `false`. The question is the existence of **what** this is testing. Since we do not know in what context this is called, we cannot tell, except that it will return `true` only when the context node has a  `anvendelse` child - which is not likely to be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of `anvendelse` tags to see if there's at least a value:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ejerlejlighed-table-only">
     <xsl:with-param name="lejligheder" select="current-group()"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="show-anvendelse" select="count(//ejerlejlighed/anvendelse) &gt; 0"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

It's not clear how you're calling the `ejerlejlighed-table-only` template, but try to use the most specific selector in the `count` to avoid performance penalties.